# How to use a view block in a dropdown menu item?

Tags: 7, views, routes, blocks, navigation

I'd like to create a menu item that generates a dropdown menu with unread [messages](https://drupal.org/project/message). I've already used [Nice Menus](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) for flyout menus, but I don't think that module supports what I'm looking for: the dropdown should be a view block and should appear when the user hoovers the 'block' in the menu bar.

Is there a module that makes this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out for following modules

[Menu Views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_views)

> Allows menu items to render views instead of links. This is useful for
>   creating "mega-menus".

[Menu Attach Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block)

> Menu Attach Block allows you to attach blocks to standard core Drupal
>   menu items. This is especially useful for creating complex dropdown
>   menus and mega menus.
>
> Any block can be used, including blocks generated by other modules.
>   Blocks generated by Views are particularly good candidates for
>   embedding.

Comment: I doubt only Nice Menu will suffice your need. Might be Menu Views with Nice menu can be a good combo for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to put blocks, views block, lists and videos into a menu, and used [tb_megamenu](https://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu). It was great. And there's a clear tutorial on all its features on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M), and quick guide [here](http://www.themebrain.com/guide/tb-mega-menu-quick-guide).